# read() return type in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using an Arduino to read from a pin and send a value over serial port. Based on the value that's returned, I would like to have python do something, but my if statement never returns true.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM7',9600)

while True:
    data = ser.read()
    print data
    if data == 'a':
            print 'data received'
```

I'm able to change the pin state and print out the value of data, which does indeed return 'a', but 'data received' is never printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure there's no newline character at the end.

Comment: @tidB has stressed a good point. Try to "line = ser.readline()" and see if 'a' in data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the implicit newline character. Change your `if` statement to:

```
if data == 'a\n':
```

Comment: Shortly after posting (and banging my head against a wall 20 minutes earlier), I realized the '\n' must have been the issue and sure enough it was. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @awwende Glad I could help. If I was helpful, consider accepting the answer with the tick after the grace period has passed. :)

Comment: Alternatively you could also `data.strip() == 'a'`

Comment: @IanAuld True, but wouldn't a direct check be faster than a `strip`, or even `rstrip`?

Comment: @AlexThornton possibly but it won't match if there is no new line char or if a different symbol is there (`\t`, `\f`, `\r\n`)